# jquery ajax returning true but not display proper message in php

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following code writing in ajax which sent a request to the back-end

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: action,
      data: str,
      success: function(msg) {
        //alert(msg);

        if (msg == 'sent') {
            alert("success");
          $('#errormessage').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Email sent successfully.</div>');
          $('.contactForm').find("input, textarea").val("");
        }else if (msg == 'saved') {
          $("#sendmessage").removeClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").addClass("show");
          $('#errormessage').html('<div class="alert alert-warning">Email couldn\'t be sent but not too worry we got it in our database. We will get back to you.</div>');
          $('.contactForm').find("input, textarea").val("");
        }

         else {
          $("#sendmessage").removeClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").addClass("show");
          $('#errormessage').html(msg);
        }

      }
    });
```

**php code**

```
$to_email = $set['Email'];

$headers = "From: ". $email;

//check if the email address is invalid $secure_check
$secure_check = sanitize_my_email($email);
if ($secure_check == false) {
    echo "Invalid input";
} else { //send email 
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO emails(name,email,subject,message)VALUES('$name','$email','$sub','$msg')");
$mail = mail($to_email,$sub,$msg,$headers);

if($query and $mail){
    echo 'sent';
}else if($query and  !$mail){
    echo 'saved';
}else{
    echo $mysqli->error;
}

}
```

If I send an email it successfully executed with the insertion. The issue I am facing is that ajax is not printing out the right message. It only execute the **else part** which displayed **sent**

This part of the code is not exected:

```
if (msg == 'sent') {
        alert("success");
      $('#errormessage').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Email sent successfully.   
       </div>');
      $('.contactForm').find("input, textarea").val("");
       }
```

instead, this is displayed with just **sent** message

```
else {
          $("#sendmessage").removeClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").addClass("show");
          $('#errormessage').html(msg);
        }
```

Comment: what is the output of the alert u have commented

Comment: It's moist likely because there's whitespace around the `sent` string you return, which means `if (msg == 'sent')` fails. Try `if (msg.trim() == 'sent')`. Better yet, use a serialised format for the response which won't be broken by the addition of whitespace. I'd suggest returning a boolean value in JSOn

Comment: @Vimal Wasn't outputting anything.

Comment: @AdeOwolaike Then how  the if condition executes?

Comment: @AdeOwolaike try to `var_dump($query);` and post the output here.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks. That solved it.

Comment: Glad it helped. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is most likely because you're returning a text-based response and there is whitespace around the value so `msg == 'sent'` is never true.

To fix this you could simply call `trim()` to remove the whitespace:

```
if (msg.trim() == 'sent') {
  // your code...
}
```

Alternatively you can change your PHP to return a serialised data structure, such as JSON or XML, to avoid this problem. I would suggest doing this.